Can I have the earlier library version compatible with newer Android version
implelementation ("com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.4")

The above library does not support the newer versions of Android such as 14, but I have legacy code so I want to use the same for not to change the whole logic (migrations not planned yet). I tried the below library but I will have to change whole logic.
implementation ("com.github.hadibtf:SemiCircleArcProgressBar:1.1.1")


Does the Circleprogress progress library have a GitHub Issues page? If so, you can ask this question of the author.
